# How to Fit Camera to Object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using three.js I have the following.

- A scene containing several Object3D instances
- Several predefined camera Vector3 positions
- A dynamic width/height of the canvas if the screen resizes
- A user can select an object (from above)
- A user can select a camera position (from above)

Given an object being viewed and the camera position they have chosen how do I compute the final camera position to "best fit" the object on screen?

If the camera positions are used "as is" on some screens the objects bleed over the edge of my viewport whilst others they appear smaller. I believe it is possible to fit the object to the camera frustum but haven't been able to find anything suitable.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a perspective camera.

You can set the camera's position, field-of-view, or both.

The following calculation is exact for an object that is a cube, so think in terms of the object's bounding box, aligned to face the camera.

If the camera is centered and viewing the cube head-on, define

```
dist = distance from the camera to the _closest face_ of the cube
```

and

```
height = height of the cube.
```

If you set the camera field-of-view as follows

```
fov = 2 * Math.atan( height / ( 2 * dist ) ) * ( 180 / Math.PI ); // in degrees
```

then the cube height will match the visible height.

At this point, you can back the camera up a bit, or increase the field-of-view a bit.

If the field-of-view is fixed, then use the above equation to solve for the distance.

---

EDIT: If you want the cube `width` to match the visible *width*, let `aspect` be the aspect ratio of the canvas ( canvas width divided by canvas height ), and set the camera field-of-view like so

```
fov = 2 * Math.atan( ( width / aspect ) / ( 2 * dist ) ) * ( 180 / Math.PI ); // in degrees
```

three.js r.69

Comment: "If the camera is centered and viewing the cube head-on" - This assumes we have moved the camera to face the bounding box? How can you generate a bounding box for a set of points that faces the camera if you don't yet know where the camera lookAt will be?

Comment: A bounding box in three.js is axis-aligned -- it is an AABB -- and is independent of the camera position or orientation.

Comment: @WestLangley : I tried your solution, and it works up to some extent. In my case, the width and length of 3D object can change based on user input. It is a house like structure, when user enter 6m, the width of object becomes 12. now it works fine until the width and length are upto 25. After that, when I rotate the object, the camera goes inside of the 3D object. It is a mobile app, so we have blocked the pinch and swell for zoom in and out manually. So user get stuck. I tried to make a fiddle, please see : https://jsfiddle.net/0z3z6y7w/86/. But that issue is not occurring in fiddle.

Comment: @WestLangley How do you get the `dist`? What do you mean by "closest face of the cube"?

Answer (score 19):

Based on WestLangleys answer here is how you calculate the distance with a fixed camera field-of-view:

```
dist = height / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * fov / 360);
```

Comment: i'm not sure where it's wrong, but it's wrong. it gets too close to the cube

Comment: Thanks for the example. I double checked the calculations and they should be correct but for some reason it gets too close to the cube and I have no idea why :(

Comment: maybe it's somehow related to the aspect ratio? it's not present in the equation

Comment: This formula is indeed incorrect and is an incorrect solve for the above formula

Comment: Could you share your solution and tell us what is wrong?

Comment: @shi: What's wrong? Just add the half of size in z-direction. Because the distance from WestLangleys answer is the distance to the nearest cube's plane so you have to move the camera farther.

user151496: in your pastebin code just add 0.5 to calc_distance, because your cube's size in z-direction is 1.

Comment: Maybe the error could come from the fact that you want to be able to see the longest distance the cube can contain. This distance is the diagonal which is equal to sqrt(W² + L²) with Width=Length for a cube.

Answer (score 13):

To calculate how far away to place your camera to fit an object to the screen, you can use this formula (in Javascript):

```
// Convert camera fov degrees to radians
var fov = camera.fov * ( Math.PI / 180 ); 

// Calculate the camera distance
var distance = Math.abs( objectSize / Math.sin( fov / 2 ) );
```

Where `objectSize` is the height or width of the object. For cube/sphere objects you can use either the height or width. For a non-cube/non-sphere object, where length or width is greater, use `var objectSize = Math.max( width, height )` to get the larger value.

Note that if your object position isn't at `0, 0, 0`, you need to adjust your camera position to include the offset.

[Here's a CodePen](http://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/obZWvK?editors=001) showing this in action. The relevant lines:

```
var fov = cameraFov * ( Math.PI / 180 );
var objectSize = 0.6 + ( 0.5 * Math.sin( Date.now() * 0.001 ) );

var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(
    0,
    sphereMesh.position.y + Math.abs( objectSize / Math.sin( fov / 2 ) ),
    0
);
```

You can see that if you grab the window handle and resize it, the sphere still takes up 100% of the screen height. Additionally, the object is scaling up and down in a sine wave fashion (`0.6 + ( 0.5 * Math.sin( Date.now() * 0.001 ) )`), to show the camera position takes into account scale of the object.

Comment: Any idea to do this the other way around? I have first-person-shooter-like controls, and I want to position a new object in the current view the camera is facing...

Comment: The trig funcion must be `tan` instead of `sin` like this:
`Math.abs( objectSize / Math.tan( fov / 2 ) );`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that object fits into screen if it's bounding sphere fits, we reduce the task to fitting sphere into camera view.

In given example we keep [PerspectiveCamera.fov](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.fov) constant while changing camera rotation to achieve best point of view for the object. Zoom effect is achieved by moving camera along .lookAt direction vector.

[image: three.js zoom extents demo]

On the picture you can see problem definition:
***given bounding sphere and camera.fov, find L, so that bounding sphere touches camera's frustum planes.***

[image: three.js zoom all camera]

Here's how you calculate desired distance from sphere to camera:

[image: three.js zoom all camera]

Complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/h7wzvbkt/

```
var renderer;
var camera;
var scene;
var orbit;
var object1;

function zoomExtents() {
  let vFoV = camera.getEffectiveFOV();
  let hFoV = camera.fov * camera.aspect;

  let FoV = Math.min(vFoV, hFoV);
  let FoV2 = FoV / 2;

  let dir = new THREE.Vector3();
  camera.getWorldDirection(dir);

  let bb = object1.geometry.boundingBox;
  let bs = object1.geometry.boundingSphere;
  let bsWorld = bs.center.clone();
  object1.localToWorld(bsWorld);

  let th = FoV2 * Math.PI / 180.0;
  let sina = Math.sin(th);
  let R = bs.radius;
  let FL = R / sina;

  let cameraDir = new THREE.Vector3();
  camera.getWorldDirection(cameraDir);

  let cameraOffs = cameraDir.clone();
  cameraOffs.multiplyScalar(-FL);
  let newCameraPos = bsWorld.clone().add(cameraOffs);

  camera.position.copy(newCameraPos);
  camera.lookAt(bsWorld);
  orbit.target.copy(bsWorld);

  orbit.update();
}

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(54, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 15;
camera.position.y = 15;
camera.position.z = 15;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xfefefe));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// create light
{
  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(0, 100, 50);
  spotLight.castShadow = true;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = 30;
  scene.add(spotLight);
}

var root = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(root);

function CustomSinCurve(scale) {
  THREE.Curve.call(this);
  this.scale = (scale === undefined) ? 1 : scale;
}

CustomSinCurve.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Curve.prototype);
CustomSinCurve.prototype.constructor = CustomSinCurve;

CustomSinCurve.prototype.getPoint = function(t) {
  var tx = t * 3 - 1.5;
  var ty = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * t);
  var tz = 0;

  return new THREE.Vector3(tx, ty, tz).multiplyScalar(this.scale);
};

var path = new CustomSinCurve(10);
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(path, 20, 2, 8, false);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x20f910,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.75
});

object1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
object1.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
object1.position.x = 22.3;
object1.position.y = 0.2;
object1.position.z = -1.1;
object1.rotation.x = Math.PI / 3;
object1.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4;

root.add(object1);

object1.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(object1.geometry.boundingSphere.radius, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00
});
material.transparent = true;
material.opacity = 0.35;
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
object1.add(sphere);

var size = 10;
var divisions = 10;
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
scene.add(gridHelper);

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Comment: I found this very useful, so thanks for the fiddle and the detailed answer. It requires some tweaking if the target object isn't positioned at 0,0,0 to start or if you don't want the orbit controls to target the center of the mesh's geometry. I also increased the z-offset by the height of the mesh, which pulls the camera back just the right amount proportionally the object's geometry, at least for my purposes.

Comment: such a shame that almost ALL three.js examples NEVER work due to breaking changes in the versions... @Alex which version of three did you use back than?

Answer (score 6):

try this for OrbitControls

```
    let padding = 48;
    let w = Math.max(objectLength, objectWidth) + padding;
    let h = objectHeight + padding;

    let fovX = camera.fov * (aspectX / aspectY);
    let fovY = camera.fov;

    let distanceX = (w / 2) / Math.tan(Math.PI * fovX / 360) + (w / 2);
    let distanceY = (h / 2) / Math.tan(Math.PI * fovY / 360) + (w / 2);

    let distance = Math.max(distanceX, distanceY);
```

Answer (score 1):

From user151496's suggestion about using the aspect ratio, this seems to work, although I've only tested with a few different parameter sets.

```
var maxDim = Math.max(w, h);
var aspectRatio = w / h;        
var distance = maxDim/ 2 /  aspectRatio / Math.tan(Math.PI * fov / 360);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question but I expected the object(s) (represented by a `Box3` as a whole) could rotate on my phone if the whole was wider than my screen so I could view it by zooming in as near as possible.

```js
const objectSizes = bboxMap.getSize();
console.log('centerPoint', centerPoint, bboxMap, objectSizes, tileMap);

//setupIsometricOrthographicCamera(bboxMap);
//https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43588/how-to-rotate-camera-centered-around-the-cameras-position
//https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object
//          Top
//      +--------+
// Left | Camera | Right
//      +--------+
//         Bottom
// canvas.height/2 / disance = tan(fov); canvas.width/2 / disance = tan(fovLR);
// => canvas.width / canvas.height = tan(fovLR)/tan(fov);
// => tan(fovLR) = tan(fov) * aspectRatio;
//If rotating the camera around z-axis in local space by 90 degrees.
//        Left
//        +---+
// Bottom |   | Top
//        |   |
//        +---+
//        Right
// => tan(fovLR) = tan(fov) / aspectRatio;
const padding = 0, fov = 50;
let aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
let tanFOV = Math.tan(Math.PI * fov / 360);
let viewWidth = padding + objectSizes.x, viewHeight = padding + objectSizes.y;
//The distances are proportional to the view's with or height
let distanceH = viewWidth / 2 / (tanFOV * aspectRatio);
let distanceV = viewHeight / 2 / tanFOV;
const camera = this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspectRatio, 0.1, 10000); //VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR
if (aspectRatio > 1 != viewWidth > viewHeight) {
    console.log('screen is more narrow than the objects to be viewed');
    // viewWidth / canvas.width => viewHeight / canvas.width
    // viewHeight / canvas.height => viewWidth / canvas.height;
    distanceH *= viewHeight / viewWidth;
    distanceV *= viewWidth / viewHeight;
    camera.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2);
}
camera.position.z = Math.max(distanceH, distanceV) + bboxMap.max.z;
//camera.lookAt(tileMap.position);
```

I had tested two different aspect of `Box3` on tow different orientations (landscape and portrait) using my phone, it worked well.

References

- [Box3.getSize ( target : Vector3 ) : Vector3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.getSize)

  > `target` — the result will be copied into this `Vector3`.
  >   Returns the width, height and depth of this box.
- [Object3D.rotateZ ( rad : Float ) : this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotateZ) (PerspectiveCamera)

  > `rad` - the angle to rotate in radians.
  >   Rotates the object around z axis in local space.
- Other answers