# How display models in optimum size un three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

i have this script to show models(converted from obj using python) in three js.

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load( "/static/android.js", addModelToScene );   

}

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
{
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    android.scale.set(1,1,1);
    scene.add( android );

}
```

this script working fine for some models. But some model are  too small. so i need to change    **android.scale.set(1,1,1);** to    **android.scale.set(10,10,10)**; to get optimum size.
then some models are too big. then i need to change     **android.scale.set(10,10,10);** to     **android.scale.set(.1,.1.1);**. How can i automatically set the size of model in three js

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object