# Fit CSS3DObject in div

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to fit my CSS3DObject when it loads on the page, however, I cannot seem to do so. THis is the jist of my code:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, containerWidth / containerHeight, 1, 100000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 1000;

var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(iframe);
scene.add(object);
```

I seem to have the correct width and height for the object, however, i cannot get the transform3d to fit my div without removing it. I need it something like:

```
-webkit-transform(0px, 0px, 0px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, ,0 ,0 , 1, 0,0, 0, -1000, 1) translate3d(0px, 0px, -1000px)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object?rq=1 does not solve your problem?

Comment: @gaitat Seems to solve it. I got one more question. Why isnt the Object being centered at the center of the div?

Comment: @gaitat I need the `translate3d(752px, 136px, 0px)` to pretty much all be `0px, 0px, 0px`