# Three.js, center camera to view all objects that is in the scene

Tags: three.js, frustum

I write an algorithm that can explode (fold and unfold) mechanical set by double clicking on then.

But i want to move the camera backward or forward after that to see all my objects in the fov.
I'm trying to use frustum to calculate intersection between frustum and objects, but i don't undestand how to use planes.
I'm working with OrthographicCamera.

What i do :

1. At every frame i recalculate the new frustum (when camera move):

   ```
   projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
   frustum.setFromMatrix(projScreenMatrix);
   ```
2. Then i do a loop over the 6 planes and bounding box of all objects in the scene :

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
           var plane = planes[i];
           for (var j = 0; j < boxs.length; j++) {
               var box = boxs[j];
               var line = new THREE.Line3(box.min, nox.max);
               //console.log({'plane': plane, 'line': line});
               if (plane.isIntersectionLine(line))
                   // move camera
           };
   };
   ```

but **plane.isIntersectionLine(line)** is always false.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: this post explains it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object

Comment: thank you, that help me found a solution. Know i have the the zoom in, i have to do the zoom out.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)