# threejs - dynamically calculate camera position using just THREE.Points

Tags: javascript, three.js

My main goal is to be able to position the camera such that my object is visible dynamically.

I have read: [How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)

which says I need `fov`, `height` and `dist`, and to me they all are unknown variables since I have not found a way to get all 3.

P.S: I'm very new to three.js

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the field of view of your camera:

```
var fov = 50;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, width/height, 0.1, 10000);
```

The higher the value of fov, the more space the camera can see.

To always have your object visible, do this:

```
camera.lookAt( object.position );
```