# Three.js Object Centering

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just started working with three.js recently and I finally have my models loading in properly. However, looking at the examples I noticed that the centering in most of the examples is done with coding like this

```
object.position.y = - 95;
```

That works fine for the example's purpose but I'm loading multiple objects of different sizes and I don't want to hard code a value for every single model. So my question is, how do you center an object dynamically?

I saw geometry.center was a way to achieve this but I couldn't find any examples and I don't understand how to add that into this example

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl

Any suggestions, tutorials, tips, or examples would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pivot point of your models is at the vertical center of your model, you can use this general approach:

```
//object.geometry.center();
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object )
var boundingBoxSize = box.max.sub( box.min );
var height = boundingBoxSize.y;
object.position.y = - height / 2;
```

And if the geometry is already shifted, you can re-center it using `geometry.center()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that code is working with a small change to the last line:

object.position.y = (height / 2) *-1;

But the issue now is the zoom being set like this

camera.position.z = 250;
and
camera.position.z = 300;

How would I do basically the same thing with the camera's zoom so it fits the object to the screen?

Comment: You are right i will correct the code. Your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23361117/4977165

Comment: In that post height equals the object height? How would I get that?

Comment: The height is the ```boundingBoxSize.y```, like in the code Ive posted above.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I was changing the code in the wrong place, it's working now. Thank you for your help!