# Put object inside viewing port in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Right now, I put my object in my 3D environment using

```
object.position.y = 5;
object.position.x = getRandomInt(-90,100);
object.position.z = getRandomInt(-50,150);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

I want to place this object not just randomly, but randomly *inside the viewport of the user*. Anyone who knows how to do this? I'm using Pointer Lock Controls.

Update:
I've managed to place the object in the center of the viewing port, using

```
object.position.x = 0;
object.position.y = 0;
object.position.z = -50;
object.position.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
```

But I want it to appear on a random position in the camera view, so... not there yet...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I misinterpreted the link you posted, but my question is about placing an object inside the viewing port, while the question you posted is about fitting the camera to an object. I don't wish to change the viewport. The viewport is determined by the users mouse via pointer lock controls.