# Auto zoom in three.js on dynamically changed object

Tags: three.js

I have a custom loaded object in three.js. I want to change dynamically its geometry by inputs' values and change distance from camera to the object.

Could someone help me how to automatically zoom in/out camera when object changes its dimensions so that the object will be fully located on the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Fit Camera to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)

Comment: Thank you. How to enable webgl in Internet explorer 8 version because almost completed my work. i don't  knowledge about enable webgl in internet explorer . Please kindly help me.