# Autodesk Forge - Initial focus on 3d view

Tags: autodesk-forge

our initial focus within our 3d views needs tweaking. Currently it is zoomed out ~x2 too far.
Can anyone get me started in the right direction for the controls for this?
I've tried changing the cropregion/ section box etc in the original revit model, but that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle that would be to position the camera as you wish then save the current state and restore it upon loading the model, see my blog post about managing viewer states: [Managing viewer states from the API](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/02/managing-viewer-states-from-the-api.html)

Comment: If you want a more generic solution that can adapt to any model, you could modify the position property of the camera so it's closer to the model, also you can take a look at what is discussed on those threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059612/calculate-camera-zoom-required-for-object-to-fit-in-screen-height, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object